# How to dynamically select an item from picklist in Vtiger 6.x

Tags: jquery, vtiger, picklist

In new ticket form, I have 2 `picklists`:

1. `Category` has 2 items: `C1` and `C2`
2. `Assigned To` has 2 items: `A1` and `A2`.

When user chooses `C1` from picklist "Category", item `A1` is selected automatically from picklist "Assigned To".
When user chooses `C2`, "Assigned To" is changed to `A2` automatically.

As I know, `Vtiger 6.x picklist` is not using `Select2 jquery` since the picklist still work when I removed `Select2 .js` files.

Answer (score 0):

There will be two options for you:

1. Write the workflow for ticket where you can add condition if category is C1 then assigned to field will be A1

   In this case you will not see the assigned to field updated in edit view but once you saved you can see the assign to field as A1
2. You can do this pragmatically using javascript:

   onchange event on catgory dropdown:- change value of assign to field.

Answer (score 0):

You can use on change event of Category Field and add below code to set value of Assigned to Field using jQuery. This will definitely help you. You have to provide your field name value in this, value which you wanted to set, and extra things which you wanted to set.

```
container.find('[name="'+key+'"]').next().children('a').children('span').text('User1');
container.find('[name="'+key+'"]').val('User1');
container.find('[name="'+key+'"]').trigger('change');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const select2value = (selector, value) => {
    value= (value)?value:'';
    $(selector).val(value); // Change the value or make some change to the internal state
    $(selector).trigger('change');
    //para versiones de vtiger 6.x
    document.querySelector(selector).parentElement.querySelector('span').innerHTML= ( $(selector).val() != '' )? $(selector).val() : '';

  };
```